# Create cron job to automatically unban users after a certain date?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I have a site with a mysql database.  I have a spot in the admin panel where administrators can ban users.  When it bans the user it makes the column "Banned"=1 and "BannedUntil"= a week after the ban date.  I want to create a cron job that runs maybe every night to unban users whos bans have expired.
So far I have this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$DB_CON = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS) or die("It failed.");
$TODAY = date('Y-m-d');
mysqli_query ($DB_CON, "UPDATE users SET Banned='0' WHERE BannedUntil < '$TODAY'");
```

I am using cPanel.
EDIT: Date is stored in the database in the format: "2014-03-24"

Comment: How have you set up the cron ? `crontab` ?

Answer (score 0):

modify your query to this

```
mysqli_query ($DB_CON, "UPDATE users SET Banned='0' WHERE BannedUntil < NOW();")
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Still doesn't seem to work, I forgot to mention though that the date is stored in the database in this format: "2014-03-24"